# How to assert Karate response with dynamic field name

Tags: api, karate

API response example:

```
{
    "topic1": [
        {"fieldName2": "value2",fieldName1": "value1"}
    ],
    "topic2": [
        {"fieldName2": "value2","fieldName1": "value1"},
        {"fieldName2":"anotherValue2","fieldName1": "anotherValue1"}
    ]
}
```

This will work:

```
Then match response.topic1 == [{"fieldName2": "value2",fieldName1": "value1"}]
And match response == {"topic1":[{"fieldName2": "value2",fieldName1": "value1"}]}
```

But I need "topic1" to be in a variable like this but cant find a way to make it work.

```
Then match response.TOPIC_NAME== [{"fieldName2": "value2",fieldName1": "value1"}]
```

Also tried `response.<TOPIC_NAME>` and `match response contains` message only but also not working.

```
    * print "KAFKA_TOPIC: ", KAFKA_TOPIC
    * print "response.KAFKA_TOPIC:", response.KAFKA_TOPIC
    * print "response.topic1: ", response.topic1
```

Logs:

```
11:47:47.946 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] KAFKA_TOPIC: topic1
11:47:47.949 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] response.KAFKA_TOPIC: null
11:47:47.951 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] response.topic1:  [
  {
    "fieldName1": "value1",
    "fieldName2": "value2",
    "fieldName2": "value3"
  }
]
```

Trying now to explore https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms
if there's no direct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access JSON with dynamic keys like this: `object[keyName]`. This is just JS behind the scenes. This example should make your options clear:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "topic1": [
    {
      "field1": "value1"
    }
  ]
}
"""
* def key1 = 'topic1'
* def val1 = response[key1]
* match val1 == [{ field1: 'value1' }]
# to do this in one line
* match (response[key1]) == [{ field1: 'value1' }]
```

Comment: Thank you Peter.
This is what I found in the documentation about enclosed JS, for others reference:
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#enclosed-javascript

Comment: @Don thanks. to be clear the need for enclosing the LHS of a `match` in brackets is a very edge case because Karate tries to process the LHS as JsonPath by default, for e.g. `response[*].foo` - explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-and-variables